# What was wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

Can anybody please explain me what was the reason my question was down voted and close without an answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590421/draw-ui-from-xml-file

Comment: As said in the closing message, you wanted to get a recommendation for a tool, which is off topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is:

> Is there any commercially available control that [...]

That would be a recommendation question, and those are specifically off-topic. This is explicitly stated in the close reason below your question:

> "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

You're simply out of luck. This question is not appropriate for any site on the network.

Comment: +1 I thought that it would be allowed on programmers, but it is not: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/question-put-on-hold-because-asking-for-tool-recommendation

Comment: Yeah @TimSchmelter, it perhaps might have been welcome in the past (I don't know enough about the history there) but currently it's a no go area.